# How do I add custom fontstyle in react app

Tags: reactjs, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts, google-fonts

I'm new to react js. I just created new React project and now I want to change the default font to my own font files

I want to add my own Fonts file to my React Project, How can I do so?

Answer (score -1):

You can install a webfont loader

**If you have yarn**

```
yarn add webfontloader
```

**If you have npm**

```
npm i webfontloader
```

You can then import it like this:

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';
```

Then, in your index.js file:

```
useEffect(() => {
  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Droid Sans', 'Chilanka']
    }
  });
 }, []);
```

and this allows you to use these fonts, like so

```
.font-loader {
  font-family: 'Chilanka';
}
```

and then you can use this class wherever you need it.

Comment: i already have fonts file in my downloads folder how to insert these files to my project

Comment: @RanaTouseef you can use font face for that purpose. See https://blog.greenroots.info/3-quick-ways-to-add-fonts-to-your-react-app